# How do I use Theano to solve an ordinary differential equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano, ode

Here is my Python code:

```
import numpy as np


def spread_points_in_cube(n, dimensions=3, rng=None):
    from scipy.integrate import ode
    if rng is None:
        rng = np.random

    size = n * dimensions
    y0 = np.zeros((2 * size))
    y0[:size] = rng.uniform(0, 0.1, size=size)
    t0 = 0.0

    mean = np.zeros(dimensions)
    variance = np.eye(dimensions) * 0

    def decode(y):
        positions = np.remainder(y[:size].reshape((n, dimensions)), 1)
        velocities = y[size:].reshape((n, dimensions))
        return positions, velocities

    def get_forces(positions, velocities):
        delta_positions = positions[:, np.newaxis, :] - positions[np.newaxis, :, :]
        delta_positions = np.remainder(delta_positions + 0.5, 1) - 0.5  # wrapping
        distances = np.linalg.norm(delta_positions, axis=2, ord=2)
        distances += 1e-5
        pairwise_forces = delta_positions * (distances ** -3)[:, :, np.newaxis]
        magnetic_forces = np.sum(pairwise_forces, axis=1) / (n ** 2)

        velocity_mags = np.linalg.norm(velocities, axis=1, ord=2)
        drag_forces = -velocities * velocity_mags[:, np.newaxis]

        forces = magnetic_forces * 0.01 + drag_forces * 10.0
        return forces

    def f(t, y):
        positions, velocities = decode(y)
        forces = get_forces(positions, velocities)
        retval = np.zeros((2 * size))
        retval[:size] = velocities.reshape(size)
        retval[size:] = forces.reshape(size)
        return retval

    r = ode(f).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf')
    r.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
    t_max = 20
    dt = 1
    while r.successful() and r.t < t_max:
        positions, velocities = decode(r.y)
        forces = get_forces(positions, velocities)
        total_speed = np.sum(np.linalg.norm(velocities, axis=1, ord=2))
        total_force = np.sum(np.linalg.norm(forces, axis=1, ord=2))
        #print("\nt", r.t, "\np", positions, "\nv", velocities,
        #      "\nf", forces
        print(total_speed, total_force)
        if total_force < n * 1e-4:
            print("breaking")
            #break
        r.integrate(r.t + dt)
    print("converged after", r.t, total_speed, total_force)
    return positions
spread_points_in_cube(1000, 3)
```

Is it possible to use Theano to solve the ODE?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to define the relevant functions in theano (and hand that function to the ODE solver)? Do you want to solve the ODE fully in theano (i.e. implementing an iterative solver in theano)? The most important question is: What is your motivation to do this?

Comment: @eickenberg this problem is computationally intensive and parallelizable. Theano should be able to implement the iteration procedure at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VERY simple ode solver in theano:

```
import numpy
import theano

# the right-hand side
def f(x, t):
    return x*(1-x)

x = theano.tensor.matrix() # why not a matrix
dt = theano.tensor.scalar()
t = theano.tensor.scalar()

x_next = x + f(x, t)*dt # implement your favourite RK method here!

# matrix of random initial values
# store it on the device
x_shared = theano.shared(numpy.random.rand(10, 10))

step = theano.function([t, dt], [],
        givens=[(x, x_shared)],
        updates=[(x_shared, x_next)],
        on_unused_input='warn')

t = 0.0
dt = 0.01

while t < 10:
    step(t, dt)
    t += dt
    # test halt condition here

print(x_shared.get_value()) # read back the result
```

I hope it helps.
Basically you have to implement your Runge-Kutta method.

And mind that the strength of theano is in vectorization, so I won't bother implementing the time loop in theano. That's why I used a simple python while loop, although I could use [theano scan](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html). Anyway, depending on your goal, the optimization can be tricky. I'm not 100% convinced that theano is a good choice for an ODE solver. Numpy does the vectorizations on your force and position matrices anyway, at least on CPU. With a theano implementation you can utilize GPU, but that's not a guarantee for a speedup.